# Generate a list of disjoint bitpointer-pairs

Tags: algorithm

Give is a set of elements, where each element has a score and a bitpointer. I want to create a list of all pairs, where the bitpointers of both of these elements are disjoint.

My naive pseudo-code approach is:

```
result = new_list_of_pairs()

foreach(i = 0; i < set.size; i++)
   foreach(j = i+1; j < set.size; j++)
      if(set[i].bitpointer & set[j].bitpointer == 0)
         result.add(set[i], set[j]);
   }
}
```

Are there better algorithms solve this problem, because the runtime of this algorithm is O(n^2)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to get better time complexity in the worst case because there can be `O(n^2)` such pairs.